# How to define Dictionary<Guid,List<Exception>> for Runtime Directives (Default.rd) in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, runtime, .net-native

So far so long, I've been having some troubles with Defualt.rd file in my UWP app. I need to define Dictinary> to the file but whatever I tried I failed. Things I tried:

```
<TypeInstantiation Name="Dictionary" Serialize="Required All" Arguments="System.Guid, System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Exception]" Dynamic="Required All" DataContractJsonSerializer="Required All" DataContractSerializer="Required All" />

<TypeInstantiation Name="Dictionary" Serialize="Required All" Arguments="System.Guid, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Exception]" Dynamic="Required All" DataContractJsonSerializer="Required All" DataContractSerializer="Required All"
```

This is the exception message being thrown from SessionStateService on suspension:

SerializationCodeIsMissingForType, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Guid,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Exception]]

I read the MSDN page ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600639(v=vs.110).aspx)) for runtime directives but didn't understand a thing, it was so complicated. I can define one noded generic types like List or Dictinary but couldn't figure out Dictionary>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generic parameters in rd.xml files are specified with curly braces in place of the angle brackets.

Ex: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Object,System.String>` 
becomes `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary{System.Object,System.String}`.

You may also find these helpful:

- https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html
- https://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/method.html